# installing packages from channels on Conda

Tags: python, package, conda

I want to install a specific package in conda env. the package called samtools and I'm pretty sure it's from the bioconda channel, just because when I look for that package in https://anaconda.org/, its written  "bioconda / samtools". So if I'm right, I promp this: `conda install -c bioconda samtools`.
Why isn't it working.
Error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - samtools

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note: `conda install -c bioconda samtools` does work for me. Weird.

Comment: any ideas why it is not working for me?

Comment: Not sure. Seems like based on your list of channels you are using apple silicon? Maybe that's affecting your results.

Comment: @topsail [Hickam's dictum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hickam's_dictum): there can always be multiple reasons for failure. In this case, yes, **osx-arm64** is not supported by Bioconda, but also, you probably have `conda-forge` (a requirement for Bioconda) in your configuration, which OP does not. Also one needs `-c conda-forge -c bioconda`, i.e. `conda-forge` must be prioritized.